# Full screen on orientation change android

Tags: java, android

I have this code to set the view to full screen. What I would like it to do is set the View to full screen on an orientation change to landscape. I have tried lots of different solutions and cant get any working, any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
public class FullScreen extends Activity {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
                            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);
}
```

}

Comment: Can you not just wrap the two lines you are using in an `if` block checking device orientation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the code for what yarian suggested:

```
public class FullScreen extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
            requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        }
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
}
```

and it's probably the best solution.

Comment: Instead of case when activity has android:configChanges="orientation screenSize" option. But I think in this case it doesn't matter. =)

Comment: With android:configChanges you set which configuration changes you want to cover by yourself using onConfigurationChanged method in Activity. So you're right, it doesn't alter anything in this case.